# Sum up custom grand total on crosstab in BIRT

Tags: birt, crosstab

I have a crosstab and create custom grand total for the row level in each column dimension, by using a data element expression.

**Crosstab Example:**

```
                       Cat 1                   Cat 2              GT
    ITEM      C    F     %     VALUE    C     F     %    VALUE
     A       101   0    0.9      10    112  105   93.8    10      20
     B       294   8    2.7       6     69   66   95.7    10      16
     C       211   7    3.3       4    212  161   75.9     6      10
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
     GT      606  15    2.47      6    393  332   84.5     8    **14**
```

**Explanation for GT row:**

1. Those **C** and **F** column is summarized from the above. But the
   **%** column is division result of F/C.
2. Create a data element to fill the **VALUE** column, which comes from range of value definition, varies for each Cat (category). For instance... in **Cat 1**, if the value is between 0 - 1 the value will be 10, or between 1 - 2 = 8, etc. And condition for **Cat 2**, between 85 - 100 = 10, and 80 - 85 = 8, etc.
3. The GT row (with the value of 14), is gathered by adding VALUE of Cat 1 + Cat 2.

I am able to work on point 1 and 2 above, but I can't seem to make it working for GT row. I don't know the code/expression to sum up the VALUE data element for this 2 categories. Because those VALUE field comes from one data element in design mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my problem. I can show the result by using a report variable. I am assigning 2 report variables in **%** field expression, based on the category in data cube dimension (by using *if* statement). And then in data element expression, I am calling both of the expressions and add them.